# Bind click event to class inside of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, setinterval, event-binding

I have been working on this the past few days and feel like I'm close, but I'm missing something. What I'm trying to accomplish is to display a modal popup when user selects a language from the google translate widget.

Since the languages which users can choose are inside of an iframe added by the javascript widget after dom has loaded, I am using setInterval to check when the iframe is available (for some reason jquery's .load() function would never work for me). I also have another setInterval method to check when the language classes have been loaded (they are not immediately available when the iframe is available).

When I bind the click event to the language elements everything works as expected...once...for whichever element is clicked. If I remove `clearInterval(waitForLanguageLinks)`, then everything works as expected everytime, but this causes a memory leak and the page eventually crashes (as one would expect).

So my question is...how can I bind a click event to each one of these elements inside of a `setInterval()` callback, and have that event remain bound after calling `clearInterval()` (hope that makes sense).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var iframe;
    var languageElements;

    var translateIframeCheck = setInterval(function(){

        iframe = $('.goog-te-menu-frame').contents();

        if(iframe.length > 0){

            clearInterval(translateIframeCheck);

        }

    }, 100);

    var waitForLanguageLinks = setInterval(function(){

        languageElements = iframe.find('.goog-te-menu2-item');

        if(typeof iframe !== "undefined" && languageElements.length > 0){

            languageElements.click(function(){

                console.log($(this).find('.text').html());

            });

            clearInterval(waitForLanguageLinks);

        }

    }, 100);    

});
```

The iframe loaded by google script for translate:

```
<iframe class="goog-te-menu-frame skiptranslate" title="Language Translate Widget" style="visibility: visible; box-sizing: content-box; width: 1004px; height: 285px; left: 413.5px; top: 167px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: The iframe is loaded dynamically by google script. Have updated question to show the iframe. There is no `src` attribute.

Comment: Sweet, so you should be good as far as XSS is concerned, :)

Comment: So when you click one of the elements in the iframe, does it cause the iframe to transition?  Or is there script inside it that just replaces the contents of the body?  If it does the latter, you could potentially delegate bind on the body of the iframe and then regardless of if the contents of the body are replaces, those bindings would exist.

Comment: The contents of the iframe are several tables that contain anchor tags with class `.goog-te-menu2-item`. The html of each of these anchor tags are the language user is selecting. The content of the iframe itself does not change. When a user clicks one of these links, google then translates the content of the iframe's parent ie the webpage.

Comment: Alright, so then try to change your bindings to be delegate event bindings then.  Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Taplar's suggestion, using [delegate event bindings](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) has resolved this issue. The following code demonstrates how to obtain the selected language from the google translate dropdown and log it into the console. This should be a good starting point for anyone who stumbles across this question in the future.

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE TRANSLATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script>
/*
    Keep in mind:
        > If google ever changes the structure of the translate element, this code
            will no longer function, and will have to be updated to reflect those
            changes.
        > There appears to be a bug in the translation widget itself where if
            a langauge other than the default langauge is chosen and the page is
            translated, then the default language is chosen again, then another
            langauge is chosen, nothing will happen, and the language must be
            selected a second time. 
*/


$(document).ready(function(){

    var iframe;

    var translateIframeCheck = setInterval(function(){

        iframe = $('.goog-te-menu-frame').contents();

        if(iframe.length > 0){


            $(iframe).on("click", ".goog-te-menu2 table tbody tr td a", function(){

                console.log($(this).find('.text').html());

            });

            clearInterval(translateIframeCheck);

        }

    }, 100);


});


</script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------------
END GOOGLE TRANSLATE -->
```